# foreach loop animation-delay +1s

Tags: php, css, foreach

The following code

```
@keyframes example {
   100% {background-color: grey;}
}
<?php
$code = 1432;
$arr1 = str_split($code);
$css = '';
foreach ($arr1 as $value) {
    $css .= '#btn' . $value . ' {';
    $css .= 'animation-name:example;';
    $css .= 'animation-duration:1s;';
    $css .= 'animation-delay:0.5s;';
    $css .= '}'; 
}

echo $css; // output variable
?>
```

**create this output:**

```
#btn1 {animation-name:example;animation-duration:1s;animation-delay:0.5s;}
#btn4 {animation-name:example;animation-duration:1s;animation-delay:0.5s;}
#btn3 {animation-name:example;animation-duration:1s;animation-delay:0.5s;}
#btn2 {animation-name:example;animation-duration:1s;animation-delay:0.5s;}
```

My problem is that the four animations begin at the same time. What should I add in my foreach loop, that every animation delay 1 second. In this example `#btn1` become animated after one second `#btn4` and so on? I know that I need to change the animation-delay every time plus 1s but I dont know how. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr1 as $index => $value) {
    $css .= '#btn' . $value . ' {';
    $css .= 'animation-name:example;';
    $css .= 'animation-duration:1s;';
    $css .= 'animation-delay:' . $index . 's;';
    $css .= '}'; 
}
```

Comment: delay for 0s makes no sense to me..other than that it is good

Comment: Thank you! Thats what I am searching for, I accept your answer in 8 minutes :)

Comment: @Andrew Delay for 0s would indicate no delay, i.e. if the user wants the first animation to begin immediately. They could just as easily write it as `($index + 1)` to have all of the animations start at 1s, then 2s, then 3s.

Comment: if no delay then the css declaration for delay is not needed...but for maintenance purposes, it is better to leave it on..

Comment: You are correct. 0s is the default value for animation-delay property and is, therefore, not required. But it doesn't hurt and, as you mention, leaving that value there allows for further customization and less ambiguity.